# Install Xdebug through Installation Wizard

Tags: php, xdebug

Can someone help me with a next step? Which software should I use and how do I go about? What is RedHat?
I have XAMPP installed. I have searched some solutions but my case is a bit different.
Below is the output from Installation Wizard (https://xdebug.org/wizard).
I do not know how to proceed from point "2.Install the pre-requisites for compiling PHP extensions." and onwards.
[image]
Summary

Xdebug installed: no

Server API: LiteSpeed V7.8 CloudLinux 1.2

Windows: no

Zend Server: no

PHP Version: 7.4.13

Zend API nr: 320190902

PHP API nr: 20190902

Debug Build: no

Thread Safe Build: no

OPcache Loaded: yes

Configuration File Path: /opt/alt/php74/etc

Configuration File: /opt/alt/php74/etc/php.ini

Extensions directory: /opt/alt/php74/usr/lib64/php/modules

**Instructions**

1.Download xdebug-3.0.1.tgz

2.Install the pre-requisites for compiling PHP extensions.

On your RedHat system, install them with:

```
yum groupinstall "Development tools" && yum install php-devel autoconf automake
```

3.Unpack the downloaded file with `tar -xvzf xdebug-3.0.1.tgz`

4.Run: `cd xdebug-3.0.1`

5.Run: `phpize` (See the FAQ if you don't have `phpize`).

As part of its output it should show:

```
Configuring for:
...
Zend Module Api No:      20190902
Zend Extension Api No:   320190902
```

If it does not, you are using the wrong phpize. Please follow this FAQ entry and skip the next step.

6.Run: `./configure`

7.Run: `make`

8.Run: `cp modules/xdebug.so /opt/alt/php74/usr/lib64/php/modules`

9.Edit  `/opt/alt/php74/etc/php.ini` and add the line
`zend_extension = /opt/alt/php74/usr/lib64/php/modules/xdebug.so`

Make sure that
`zend_extension = /opt/alt/php74/usr/lib64/php/modules/xdebug.so`
is below the line for OPcache.

10.Restart the webserver

Comment: Fell free to ask me counter questions if you like. I am really new to this, and unsure how everything works. My goal is to be able to debug php code in my Wordpress's plugin.I am stuck on point 2 and onwards.

Comment: So, as a new user, take the [tour] and read [ask] to get familiar with this. That said, you ask "What is RedHat?", which shows that you need to do a bit research online. Sorry, but  if you throw that question at a random search engine, you will find an answer to it. I think it isn't too much to ask that preliminary work first.

Comment: Yes, but RedHat is something for Linux...my computer runs on Windows, so that in itself would be an issue. But to what forum should I go then? You can give me something to start with. My computer knowledge is limited.

Answer (score 1):

You're reading the *nix (Linux) installation instructions.

1. Install link is at the top of the website.
2. That brings you to https://xdebug.org/docs/install.
3. The *eighth line on the page*: `Windows, with help from a wizard`.
4. Brings you to https://xdebug.org/wizard
5. With instructions to download files from https://xdebug.org/download.
6. And to copy the contents of your `php.ini` file in the textarea at https://xdebug.org/wizard.

After following those clear instructions you will need to restart your HTTP server or if you have no idea and don't mind a temporary mindless brute-force (for your current XP) just sacrilegiously reboot your computer.

Here is what is in my WAMP (Windows, Apache, MariaDB, PHP) server's `php.ini` file for XDebug:

```
[XDebug]
;When updating server dump phpinfo in to here to determine correct download: https://xdebug.org/wizard.php
zend_extension = "C:\MEDIA\INTERNET\WAMP\PHP\ext\php_xdebug-2.9.7-7.4-vc15-x86_64.dll"
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "C:\MEDIA\INTERNET\WAMP\Apache\logs"
xdebug.profiler_append = On
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = On
xdebug.profiler_output_name = "callgrind.%R-%u.trace"
xdebug.trace_options = 1
xdebug.collect_params = 4
xdebug.collect_return = 1
xdebug.collect_vars = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable=0
xdebug.trace_output_dir = "C:\MEDIA\INTERNET\WAMP\Apache\logs"
html_errors = 0
```

If installed correctly you should be able to simply append `?XDEBUG_PROFILE` to the end of a URL (from your local server). The files will be output to whatever you set for `xdebug.profiler_output_dir` (use quotes if there are spaces in your local file system's path).

To open the generated logs I recommend using [QCacheGrind](http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/html/Home.html).

If you get stuck leave a comment. It appears that you're likely having trouble concentrating because the vast majority of the instructions are very easy to access. Additionally you should make an attempt to find search the web before asking questions that are easy to find by...searching the web. Good luck.

Comment: The above phpinfo from Xdebug Installation Wizard is from my live website's PHP configuration. So that is my host's configurations. I do not think I can install Xdebug at their server. But now I have downloaded XAMPP and have Xdebug installed on my PC, that is, local hosted. I guess I have to migrate my Wordpress site to my PC, which would be my second choise after being able to debug my live site instead. I will also download Eclipse.

Comment: You should talk with your host to see if you can use it. Frankly you should be testing local first and then push changes to the live server.